# Can I do `blocking-subscribe` in a scheduled task which runs repeatedly?

Tags: clojure, rabbitmq, quartz-scheduler, langohr

Recently I've found my Clojure/Ring/Jetty server repeatedly go into `NoClassDefFoundError` when I `cider-connect` into it and do something.  I guess that is because the thread pool being exhausted by some dead threads.

Then I've found this function in the server which runs one time every day by a definition `clojurewerkz.quartzite.scheduler` job:

```
(defn consumer-msgs-announcement
  [rabbitmq queue-name & args]
  (with-open [conn (lc/connect rabbitmq)]
    (let [ch  (lch/open conn)]
      (lq/declare ch queue-name {:durable false :auto-delete false})
      (println " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
      ;; (lcons/blocking-subscribe ch queue-name msg-queue/post-wxmsg-handle-delivery {:auto-ack true})
      (lcons/blocking-subscribe ch queue-name handle-delivery-announcement {:auto-ack true})
      )))
```

in which included packages are defined as:

```
   [langohr.core :as lc]
   [langohr.channel :as lch]
   [clojure.string :as str]
   [langohr.queue :as lq]
   [langohr.consumers :as lcons]
```

I doubt the `blocking-subscribe` will cause the thread which it used to be blocked forever which exhausts the thread pool of JVM and finally causes the `NoClassDefFoundError` error.

I am not sure about this, but can I do `blocking-subscribe` in a scheduled task which runs repeatedly?

Is the thing I described above possible? Or are there any wrong with my deduction?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure about my deduction. Can you help me with that? I updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience `blocking-subscribe` does block the thread indefinitely. You can quickly check the [source](https://github.com/michaelklishin/langohr/blob/master/src/clojure/langohr/consumers.clj#L159) for `blocking-subscribe` to see that it goes into a do-seq on a potentially endless lazy-seq.

It looks like you just want to have your job collect any existing messages that have backed up in the queue since the last run. Here are a couple of options that stick out to me for this style of access pattern.

1. You can use [langohr.basic/get](https://github.com/michaelklishin/langohr/blob/master/src/clojure/langohr/basic.clj#L183) in order to process messages on the queue until you receive a `nil`.
2. You can use `langohr.consumers/subscribe` to create a simple non-blocking consumer

   - Start the consumer
   - Keep the consumer tag you get
   - Sleep for a predetermined amount of time
   - Cancel the consumer using langohr.basic/cancel

P.S. I am unable to post the link to the `subscribe/cancel` documentation, but it's easy to find in the source and in the langohr API reference.

Comment: Thanks. Learned a lot from your answer.